# How to soft delete with WPF DataGrid and Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, wpf, entity-framework-4, datagrid, savechanges

Suppose I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLETABLE (
     ID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL,
     DELETIONDATE DATE, 
     NAME VARCHAR2(100 CHAR) NOT NULL, 
     UNIQUE (DELETIONDATE, NAME));
```

How to soft delete an item from a WPF `DataGrid`? Soft deletion is the operation below:

```
UPDATE EXAMPLETABLE 
SET DELETIONDATE = NOW()
WHERE ID = SOMEID;
```

Should I handle the KeyPress event?
In the form I have a Save button, should I do some treatment before calling `entities.SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havn't provided a lot of information about how you use the datagrid so I will have to make some assumptions.

If you want the "soft deletion" to happen when the user deletes a row from the datagrid you need to enable deletion of rows. You do that by setting `CanUserDeleteRows` to `True`.

I assume that you are using some kind of databinding to bind the rows in the datagrid. When a row is deleted the underlying object in `ItemsSource` is removed from that collection. If you use a collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` (like [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)) an event is fired when that happens.

You can listen to that event and modify the underlying model object accordingly by setting `DeletionDate` to `DateTime.Now`. You will then have to call `entities.SaveChanges()` to push that change to the database.

```
private void ReloadData()
{
    var viewSource = (CollectionViewSource)this.FindResource("aTableViewSource");
    var aTableRows = new ObservableCollection<aTable>
    (
        this.entities.aTable
            .Where(fibra => !fibra.DELETIONDATE.HasValue)
            .Take(10)
            .ToList()
    );

    fibras.CollectionChanged += EventHandler;
    fibrasViewSource.Source = aTableRows;
}

void EventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        foreach(var oldItem in e.OldItems)
        {
            ((aTable)oldItem).DELETIONDATE = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```